# Frequency of flute note heard using Doppler effect when both the source and observer are moving

Tags: homework-and-exercises, doppler-effect

Let us consider this scenario. A bicycle rider and a flute player are moving 
in the same direction at speeds 36 km/h and 18 km/h. The flute is producing 
a note of frequency 600 Hz. We need to find out the frequency of note heard
by the bicycle rider before and after crossing the flute player if the 
velocity of sound is 340 m/s.

We have the Doppler effect formula,

$$f_\text{observed} = \frac{v+u_o}{v-u_s}\times f,$$

where, $u_o$ and $u_s$ are the velocity of the observer
and sound producer.

Under the given scenario, neither  the observer nor the sound producer
is stationary. 
We are rather confused how we take the signs of 
$u_o$ and $u_s$.

---

**UPDATE 1**

Based on the comments we received are the following solutions correct?

***The bicycle is approaching the flute***

The observer is moving towards the source, so 
$u_o$ is +ve. The source is moving away from the observer, so $u_s$
is -ve.

Hence,

$$f_\text{observed} = \frac{340+36\times1000/3600}{340+18\times1000/3600}\times 600 = 608.696\ \text{Hz}$$

***The bicycle is moving away from the flute***

The observer is moving away from the source, so 
$u_o$ is -ve. The source is moving towards the observer, so $u_s$
is +ve.

Hence,

$$f_\text{observed} = \frac{340-36\times1000/3600}{340-18\times1000/3600}\times 600 = 591.045\ \text{Hz}$$

---

**UPDATE 2**

We solve the same problem using relative velocities.
Let us consider the source to be stationary.

***The bicycle is approaching the flute***

The observer is moving towards the source at a velocity, 
$(36-18)\times 1000/3600 = 5$ m/s. So, this relative $u_o$ is +ve. The source is 
stationary, so $u_s$
is zero.

Hence,

$$f_\text{observed} = \frac{340+5}{340+0}\times 600 = 608.824\ \text{Hz}$$
*(differs from the previous answer)*

***The bicycle is moving away from the flute***

The observer is moving away from the source, 
5 m/s. So 
$u_o$ is -ve. The source is moving towards the observer,  $u_s$
is zero.

Hence,

$$f_\text{observed} = \frac{340-5}{340+0}\times 600 = 591.176\ \text{Hz}$$ 
*(differs from the previous answer)*

Looks like either (or even both) of the above method is (are) incorrect.

You can tell us what is wrong.

Comment: Luckily, in nonrelativistic scenarios like this :-) you can change your frame of reference to give one of the players a velocity of zero.  That will simplify your efforts.

Comment: @Carl: doesn't the air have to be at rest to use the equation?

Comment: @JavierBadia I don't think sound is significantly affected by the speed (or lack thereof) of the transmitting medium.